# VTK Position Camera to Fill Viewport with Object

Tags: c++, ios, vtk

I have an image plane that receives streaming video from the camera. I'm trying to place that image in front of the camera such that it fills the screen. However, I'm having trouble calculating the distance the camera needs to be from the image.

```
auto camera = this->renderer()->camera();
double *origin = imageData->GetOrigin();
int *extent = imageData->GetExtent();
double *spacing = imageData->GetSpacing();
double viewportHeight = this->renderer()->camera()->viewport()->height();

this->Internal->cameraImagePlaneRepresentation()->setImageData(imageData);

double imageCenterX = origin[0] + 0.5f * (extent[0] + extent[1]) * spacing[0];
double imageCenterY = origin[1] + 0.5f * (extent[2] + extent[3]) * spacing[1];
double imageWidth = (extent[1] - extent[0] + 1.f) * spacing[0];
double imageHeight = (extent[3] - extent[2] + 1.f) * spacing[1];

double viewAngleRadians = degreesToRadians(camera->viewAngle());
double hypotenuse = imageHeight / viewAngleRadians;
double distance = tan(viewAngleRadians * 0.5f) * hypotenuse;

camera->setFocalPoint(vesVector3f(imageCenterX, imageCenterY, 0.f));
camera->setPosition(vesVector3f(imageCenterX, imageCenterY, distance));
```

I would think the distance would be correct, but it is off by an order of magnitude.

Comment: isn't hypotenuse = imageHeight / sin(viewAngleRadians) ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It greatly helps if you get the formula right for calculating distance.

```
double viewAngleRadians = degreesToRadians(camera->viewAngle());
double distance = imageHeight / viewAngleRadians;
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer so that the question is "closed"?

Comment: @DavidDoria you have to wait 24 hours.